# How to patch an existing CMake project

Tags: cmake

The project, I am currently working on, is based on another open source project `foo`. CMake allows me to easily include this project into my build system:

```
...
add_subdirectory(foo)
...
```

I  need to make some changes to `foo`, but I do not want to touch the originakl project. More precisely, there are a couple of source files of `foo` that require minor changes to remain compatible with my project. Is there a possibility in CMake to load the original project and then to patch it with my changes?

Some sources refer to `cmake -E`, but I could not find a documentation. Is this what I am looking for or what other solutions do exist?

Comment: `make some changes to foo, but I do not want to touch the originakl project` Then how do you want to make these changes? Don't you have a copy of the files on your pc? `Is there a possibility in CMake to load the original project and then to patch it with my changes?` So why not `patch` it before "loading" in cmake? Do you use some version control system, like git? `I could not find a documentation` It's right here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool

Comment: vcpkg has good support for this via "overlay ports". I would recommend vcpkg over add_subdirectory or any other hand-rolled solution for complex dependency management like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) module
2. Clone the upstream repo. Add your patch and use this repo (as a Git submodule or with the CMake module above). Add `upstream` remote and get changes from upstream from time to time. Or (the best) convince the maintainers to include your patch to upstream version ;)